# Inserting into database with auto increment

Tags: java, mysql

I need to store some values into my table using prepared statements.

I have a column in my table called id, and it is set to auto increment. I do not need any input from the user for this column.

The other values are all gotten from the user.

Edit: There are 2 IDs. One from the user and one that is auto generated from the database. The one automatically generated by the database is the primary key.

Am I doing this right?

Thanks.

Prepared Statement:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `insert_details`(IN id varchar(45),IN username varchar(45),IN name varchar(45)) 

BEGIN insert into details (id,username,name) values (id ,username,name);

END
```

Code:

```
PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connect.prepareStatement("CALL INSERT_DETAILS(?,?,?)");
preparedStatement.setLong(1, userID);
preparedStatement.setString(2, username);
preparedStatement.setString(3, name);

preparedStatement .executeUpdate();
```

Comment: Is there a reason for using a stored procedure here?  Could you simply do `connect.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO details(id, username, name) VALUES (?, ?, ?)");` instead?

Comment: Yes I could, but aren't stored procedures more secure?

Comment: Not really.  In this case, the security is provided by using prepared statements to sanitize the input data and prevent injection attacks.  Stored procedures are usually reserved for consolidating logic that multiple clients might make use of.

Comment: String sql = "INSERT INTO details (id, username, name)" +"VALUES (?, ?, ?)";     
statement.executeUpdate(sql);

Comment: Is that the right way?

Comment: Looks ok to me.  For what it's worth, prepared statements are also used sometimes in Oracle shops where DBAs have more power than developers and ordinary programs don't have INSERT or UPDATE privs. But if you aren't working in such a shop, don't waste your time using SPs for this security purpose. If you are, well, you probably have a good reason to be there.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply omit auto-generated field from the prepared statement as MySQL will set this value for you.  In your example, your parameter names are colliding with table attribute names.  The convention that I follow is to prefix parameter names with a `p_` or similar name mangling.

The prepared statement should look more like the following:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE
  DEFINER=`root`@`localhost`
PROCEDURE `insert_details`(
  IN p_user_id VARCHAR(45),
  IN p_username VARCHAR(45),
  IN p_name VARCHAR(45))
BEGIN
  INSERT
    INTO details(id, username, name)
    VALUES (p_user_id, p_username, p_name);
END $$
```

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention, there are 2 IDs. One from the user and one from the database. The one automatically generated by the database is the primary key.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `id` field from your prepared statement.

Because it will conflict the field data so problem may occur.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention, there are 2 IDs. One from the user and one from the database. The one automatically generated by the database is the primary key.